# Joomla Add <style> in article

Tags: css, joomla

In Joomla how can I add a style to a article like this?
I try to edit the html in the editor but the editor deletes everything inside style

```
<style>
    span{
        color: #0099ff;
    }
    img{
        float: right;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <h3>
        <span>
            <strong>
                <em>Water Innovation through Dissemination & Exploitation of Smart Technologies</em>
            </strong>
        </span>
    </h3>
    <img src="/images/home/ict4water_projects_logos.png" alt="ICT4Water projects logos" width="400" height="225"/>
</div>
```

Comment: why don't you use them inside your external stylesheet?

Comment: Use your external stylesheet or inline styles, eg `<span style="color: #0099ff"> </span>`

Comment: im asking to do it with <style>, or how can i disable the automatic delete of <style>?

Comment: try https://www.joomla-monster.com/blog/joomla-3-0/how-to-stop-joomla-editor-from-cleaning-some-html-elements

Comment: You can use the Sourcer plugin - https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer

Comment: @Narek-T thanks but it seems not working well. I will try to addit In external file

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily turn OFF the editor at the global settings to save an article  or setup allowed tags list at the editor settings.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to avoid embedded CSS whenever possible. Have you tried adding your custom CSS to your template's template.css file (or a custom.css file if it has one)?

In lieu of that, what Victor Yuoshev suggested will work HOWEVER any future updates to that particular article will always have to be done with the editor turned off, otherwise when you go to save it your embedded CSS will just get stripped out again.